# Convert timedelta to floating-point

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, floating-point, timedelta

I got a timedelta object from the subtraction of two datetimes. I need this value as floating point for further calculations.
All that I've found enables the calculation with floating-points, but the result
is still a timedelta object.

```
time_d = datetime_1 - datetime_2
time_d_float = float(time_d)
```

does not work.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could use the [`total_seconds`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method:

```
time_d_float = time_d.total_seconds()
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'.

Comment: `timedelta.total_seconds()` was introduced in Python 2.7/3.2

Comment: @aaa90210 - it's a method and should be used with ()

Comment: [Not to be confused with `timedelta.seconds`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653034/812102) (which returns an int, BTW).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou furthermore, it doesn't round up for you - it's the literal seconds value without the milliseconds.

Answer (score 48):

[In Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#datetime-and-time) or higher, you can divide two `timedelta`s to give a float.  This is useful if you need the value to be in units other than seconds.

```
time_d_min = time_d / datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
time_d_ms  = time_d / datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

Comment: I see this as the most natural way to do it. Besides that, it's also great for adapting time implementations of other languages/systems.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **numpy** to solve that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time_d = datetime_1 - datetime_2

#for a single value
number_of_days =pd.DataFrame([time_d]).apply(np.float32)

#for a Dataframe
number_of_days = time_d.apply(np.float32)
```

Hope it is helpful!

Comment: I get this error with your suggestion: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Hi @lancew, thanks for catching that! In that case, I needed to convert a dataframe to float so it worked out for me. If you want to convert a unique value, you could do it: `pd.DataFrame([time_d]).apply(np.float32)` . In this case, you need to import both 'pandas as pd' and 'numpy as np'. Although I'll be testing other ways. Please, let me know if it works.

Comment: Now, I get this error: "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timedelta'"

Comment: I had a similar issue. I solved it using `to_numpy()` e.g. `df["column"].to_numpy().astype(float)`. Also see solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370756/python-pandas-dataframe-how-to-convert-timedelta-column-to-float-column.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed the number of days as a floating number you can use timedelta's days attribute

```
time_d = datetime_1 - datetime_2
number_of_days = float(time_d.days)
```

Comment: This gives the number of days only. You lose whatever amount of hours minutes or seconds you have in time_d. This is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
x1= timedelta(seconds=40, minutes=40, hours=5)
x2= timedelta( seconds=50, minutes=20, hours=4)
x3=x1-x2
x5 = x3.total_seconds()
print(x5)
print(type(x5))
print(type(x1))
print(x1)

# if you are working with Dataframe then use loop (* for-loop).
```

Answer (score -5):

I had the same problem before and I used timedelta.total_seconds to get Estimated duration into seconds with float and it works. 
I hope this works for you.

```
from datetime import timedelta,datetime

time_d = datetime_1 - datetime_2

time_d.total_seconds()
```

Comment: How does this add anything over the currently-accepted answer?