# Python: Pandas Dataframe How to Convert timedelta column to float column

Tags: python, types, timedelta

I have a column in a dataframe that has datatype [timedelta64[ns]].  I'm trying to convert it to a float.

This is a sample table:

```
ColA
227 days 00:00:00.000000000
316 days 00:00:00.000000000
226 days 00:00:00.000000000
153 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

Below is my desired table with datatype as float:

```
ColA
227 
316  
226  
153
```

This is the code I tried:

```
df_EVENT5_24['ColA'] = df_EVENT5_24['ColA'].astype(float)
```

This is the error: 
TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [float64]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` to access the attribute `days` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
df_EVENT5_24['ColA'] = df_EVENT5_24.apply(lambda row: row.ColA.days, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the dt.days attribute. Example ColA is the name of your timedelta Series.

```
ColA = ColA.dt.days
```

To convert into a float,  you need either df.astype

```
ColA = ColA.astype(float)

***ColA = ColA.dt.days.astype(float)***
```