# Python timedelta seconds vs total_seconds

Tags: python, datetime

Looking at the datetime [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), I can't seem to get the difference between the attribute `seconds` and the method `total_seconds()` used on a timedelta object. Is it just precision? That the former is an *int* and the latter a *float*? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can construct a `timedelta` from days, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours and weeks. Please note the order of these parameters, which is absolutely not useful and probably caused historically.

Internally, the `timedelta` structure is only made up of days, seconds and microseconds. And these are the properties you can access once the `timedelta` has been built. Even if you used hours, minutes etc. to construct the object, that information is gone.

```
import datetime

t = datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
print(t.seconds)
```

If seconds become larger than 86400 (24*60*60), they will overflow into one day:

```
import datetime

t = datetime.timedelta(hours=24, minutes=1)
print(t.seconds)
print(t.days)
```

And thus, `timespan.seconds` is quite a useless property, because it's only a part of the truth and meaningless without the other two components. The same applies for `timespan.days` and `timespan.microseconds`. They should really have been made internal and thus adhere to the principle of information hiding.

`total_seconds()` on the other hand side, is a valid representation of the timespan. It considers all 3 properties combined into a single number.

Comment: "Internally, the timedelta structure is only made up of days, seconds and microseconds." - This is the missing piece I needed to demystify what's happening.  Very bad, unintuitive design - and poorly documented.  :(  Thank you, Thomas, for saving me.

Answer (score 55):

`seconds` is the number of seconds within a day, which is in [0, 86399].  `total_seconds` is the entire timedelta converted to seconds, and can be any value, for example 604800.0 for one week, or 0.1 for 100 milliseconds.

Comment: I see now that the docs say that seconds are `Between 0 and 86399 inclusive`, i.e. number of seconds in a day. So for timedeltas less than a day, seconds and total_seconds would be identical, given that you don't use millisecond resolution. Still don't understand why the seconds attribute just couldn't be the total number of seconds in that timedelta though. Legacy thing?

Comment: @toringe: Sorry I had a mistake in my answer - I've fixed it now.