# time difference with Timedelta gives wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am using python to calculate the time difference in hour. However, I get wrong result. Here is my code and I get 18.4 hour but the answer shoube be much more definitely!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-15 16:39:46')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-21 11:03:59')
print(pd.Timedelta(t2 - t1).seconds/3600.0)
```

Comment: You need total_seconds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652952/python-timedelta-seconds-vs-total-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing days, I think you need `total_seconds()`:

```
print(pd.Timedelta(t2 - t1).total_seconds()/3600)
```

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> timedelta.total_seconds()
>
> > Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration.
> >     Equivalent to
> >
> > `(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10 **6) / 10 **6`
> >
> > computed with true division enabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you have series , I think `astype('timedelta64[s]')` can do what you need

```
pd.Series(t1-t2).astype('timedelta64[s]')/3600
0   -138.403611
dtype: float64
```